# Camadas para desenvolver web service

Tags: php, c#, java, .net, arquitetura-de-software

Estou desenvolvendo utilizando REST (com API RestFull), onde penso em utilizar no sistema duas camadas: BLL e DAL.

BLL => Seria a camada referente às regras de negócio.

DAL => Seria a camada responsável pelo acesso aos dados. Poderia ser DAO também, sendo esta última onde o acesso através de objetos.

Para uma arquitetura estilo REST, esta seria um boa alternativa? Que outros padrões, camadas ou alternativas existem para o caso de arquitetura REST?

OBS:
Estou trabalhando com PHP mas acredito que a linguagem não se torna relevante para este caso.

Comment: Poderia ser DAO também, mas à principio DAL.

Comment: DAL = Data Access Layer

Comment: BLL = Business Logic Layer. Há quem está acostumado como BL (Business Layer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anderson,

Dentro de uma arquitetura Rest-Style, a maneira como você acessa um repositório de dados para produzir suas resources/mensagens, ou para consumi-las, não é um dos temas centrais das premissas de serviços publicados em Rest(Restful Services)

Em outras palavras, a maneira como vc vai fazer isso, se com DAO ou com outros padrões de Design, não vão afetar diretamente a sua arquitetura Rest-style. Você pode até mesmo ter métodos com memoização para responder a requisições mais rápidamente.

**O DAO, como primeira opção**

Na minha experiência eu trabalhei em diversos projetos com diferentes arquiteturas, a que ofereceu mais flexibilidade e Separation Of Concerns foi o DAO com um framework de Injeção de Dependencia - Spring por exemplo. Eu costumo injetar as implementações das interfaces da camada DAO, o mesmo para os BOs

Premissas Rest

Se você está preoculpado com seguir os guidelines da arquitetura Rest-style, de  uma lida nelas aqui: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

A linguagem onde o serivço é implementado de fato não importa, apenas lembre-se que em rest HTTP não é uma camada de transporte, mas sim é enxergado como uma API:

- POST
- GET
- DELETE
- PUT

Ou seja, métodos HTTP são vistos como  métodos de uma API.

**Considere JAX-RS**

JAX-RS fornece uma camada de abstração excelente para criação e exposição de serviços em Rest, é considerado o *State-of-Art* dentro da plataforma Java

Por útimo, recomendo a leitura deste documento:

http://www2008.org/papers/pdf/p805-pautassoA.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Eu utilizo algo parecido, porém faço da seguinte maneira:

Eu evito ficar trafegando com as entidades de banco de dados entre todas as camadas da aplicação, assim eu acabo definindo um ponto, onde meus serviços e minhas regras de negócios não enxergue as entidades e sim um Data Transfer Object(DTO). Por exemplo:

> ***ProdutoResource*** = Camada onde fica definido os serviços.
>
> ***ProdutoService*** = Camada onde fica definida as regras de negócios
>
> ***ProdutoRepository*** = Camada de repositórios onde persisti as entidades na base de dados.

Entre a camada de regra de negócios e repositórios, que eu faço a conversão de DAO para DTO ou vice-versa.

Este é padrão em particular que eu adoto.

Claro que existem 'n' variáveis ainda a se considerar, como a API Gateway, para que o cliente não chegue diretamente ao seu endpoint, também tem o front-end e por ai vai.